# Smooth connection between piecewise parts

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Example piecewise wise function:

```
f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{x^2, 0<x<1-epsilon},{x,1<x<2-epsilon},{2,x>2}}]
```

Is there a way to connect these parts in interval epsilon, so I get a smooth function?
EDIT: 
By smooth, I don't mean it needs to be derivable in point of connection, just that in some numerical work it looks like a "natural" connection.
EDIT2:
Two black circles represent the points where lies the problem. I'd like it to look like a derivable function (although it doesn't need to be in rigor mathematical sense, but I don't want these two spikes). Red circle represents the part where it looks good.
[image: picture]

What I could do is do this by nonlinear fitting the [x-epsilon, x+epsilon], but I was hoping that there was an easier way with piecewise function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, given a function we should define it precisely on the whole range `{x,0,2}`, ie. its values on ranges `1-epsilon <= x < 1` and `2 - epsilon <= x < 2`.
[image]

The easiest way is to define `f1[x]` piecewise linear on the both ranges, however the resulting function wouldn't be differentiable on the gluing points, and it would involve spikes.

To prevent such a situation we should choose (in this case) at least third order polynomials there:

```
P[x_] := a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d
```

and glue them together with `f[x]` assuming "gluing conditions" (equality of functions at given points as well as of their first derivatives) ie. solve resulting equations  :

```
W[x_, eps_]:= P[x]//. Flatten@Solve[{#^2 == P[#],
                                     1   == P[1], 
                                     2#  == 3a#^2 +2b# +c, 
                                     1   == 3a +2b +c},   {a, b, c, d}]&@(1-eps)

Z[x_, eps_]:= P[x]//. Flatten@Solve[{#  == P[#],
                                     2  == P[2], 
                                     1  == 3a#^2 +2b# +c, 
                                     0  == 12a +4b +c},  {a, b, c, d}]&@(2-eps)
```

To visualise the resuls we can take advantege of `Manipulate` :

```
f1[x_, eps_]:=  Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <  x < 1 -eps}, {W[x, eps], 1 -eps <= x < 1},
                           { x , 1 <= x < 2 -eps}, {Z[x, eps], 2 -eps <= x < 2},
                                                   {    2    ,           x >=2}}]; 
Manipulate[ Plot[f1[x, eps],  {x, 0, 2.3}, 
                 PlotRange ->    {0, 2.3}, ImageSize->{650,650}]
                                                        //Quiet, {eps, 0, 1}]
```

Depending on `epsilon > 0` we get differentiable functions `f1`, while for `epsilon = 0` `f1` is not differentiable at two points.

```
Plot[f1[x, eps]/. eps -> .4, {x, 0, 2.3}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.3}, 
                             ImageSize -> {500, 500}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]
```

[image]

If we wanted f1 to be a smooth function (infinitely differentiable) we should play around defining `f1` in range `[1 - epsilon <= x < 1)` with a transcendental function, something like for example `Exp[1/(x-1)]` etc.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries both are good answers, I would give you both the solved flag, unfortunately the +1 will have to do. Artes Docendo I think that Manipulate is a good idea.

Comment: @Verbeia No I haven't. I'm not sure how to give a support, is following the topic enough?

Answer (score 4):

You could do a gradually change between the functions that define the begin and end point of the interval. Below I do this by shifting the weight in the weighted sum of these functions depending on the position in the interval:

```
ClearAll[f]
epsilon = 0.1;
f[x_] :=
 Piecewise[
  {
   {x^2, 0 < x < 1 - epsilon},
   {Rescale[x, {1 - epsilon, 1}, {1, 0}] x^2 + Rescale[x, {1 - epsilon, 1}, {0, 1}] x, 
      1 - epsilon <= x <= 1}, 
   {x, 1 < x < 2 - epsilon},
   {Rescale[x, {2 - epsilon, 2}, {1, 0}] x + Rescale[x, {2 - epsilon, 2}, {0, 1}] 2, 
      2 - epsilon <= x <= 2},
   {2, x > 2}
   }
  ]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but from what I gather here is an idea

```
ClearAll[f]
e = 0.1
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 < x < 1 - e}, {whatEver, 
    1 - e <= x <= 1 + e}, {x, 1 + e < x < 2}, {2, x > 2}}, error]
```

`f[1]` the gives whatEver.